# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', " <!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON error after moving to a different server

Tags: apache, nginx, laravel-filament, filamentphp

Im using filamentphpv2 for the admin panel, but I get a blank login screen without any errors, then when I enter the login credentials and click login nothing happens, but an error message appears in the console.
[image]

I have no idea how I could fix it, because it worked on the previous server, and even now if I put it on a different server it works there also. Sad thing is it has to work on the current server where for some reason it doesnt.

The servers where it works are nginx servers and where I get this error is apache.

Comment: What's the HTTP response header `content-type`?

Comment: its 
text/html; charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when we are pointing to the wrong URL while performing CRUD operations. If you have moved to a new server where you are using Apache instead of Nginx, I would recommend comparing the configuration files and double-checking the **URL** and **PORT**.

One easy way to do this is by checking the console of your browser, which will show you where the error is emanating from. Then, cross-check your desired URLs and PORT with the ones exposed by the server.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, which configuration files? I am not the one who handles the servers and the migration of this site btw, but im the one expected to solve this problem.
The console in the browser only shows the error which is in the OP. 
cross-check your desired URLs and PORT with the ones exposed by the server. - could you eloborate more on this please?

Comment: chaning from apache back to nginx solved it